# Test cases fail when running in chrome using selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, selenium

am facing some problem when running tests in chrome. when i run the same tests in firefox it works fine... but when i run them in chrome... it fails.... here is the sample code

> driver.findElement(By.className("vO")).sendKeys("testmail@gmail.com");
>   driver.findElement(By.className("aoT")).sendKeys("Test Mail");
>   Thread.sleep(5000); WebElement frame1 =
>   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@tabindex='1']"));
>   driver.switchTo().frame(frame1); WebElement editable =
>   driver.switchTo().activeElement(); String mailBody = "Hi," + '\n';
>   editable.sendKeys(mailBody);

any help on this...????

Comment: Care to tell us *how* it fails?

Comment: Hi... sorry for the late response.. well its not typing in the mailbody... although when i run the same script in firefox it works good!! i still could not figure it out on why is it failing.. it says the element is not found... in firefox its good..!! :(